# R: connecting R with Eurequa, Rcpp compile error

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to run Eurequa from within R.
http://code.google.com/p/eureqa-api/
I am using the code below but I get a compile error:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! 


library(Rcpp)
library(inline) 
rcpp1 <- '


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{




  // initialize data set and options
  eureqa::data_set data("abc1.txt");
  eureqa::search_options options("y = f(x)");

  // connect to a eureqa server
  eureqa::connection conn("127.0.0.1");
  conn.send_data_set(data);
  conn.send_options(options);
  conn.start_search();

  // display results
  eureqa::search_progress progress;
  eureqa::solution_frontier solutions;

  while (conn.query_progress(progress))
  {
    solutions.add(progress.solution_);
    std::cout << progress.summary() << std::endl;
    std::cout << solutions.to_string() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
'


rcpp2 <- cxxfunction(
                       rcpp1, plugin="Rcpp", 
                       includes=c('#include  <eureqa/eureqa.h>, <iostream>'))




rcpp2()
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what is the error?

And while you told `cxxfunction()` about one header file, you may still have to tell the compiler where to get it from --- and presumably also have to tell the compiler (which calls the linker) about which library to link with, and where to find it.  The 'Rcpp-FAQ' vignette has an example about how to tell `cxxfunction()` where to find GSL headers and libraries.

Lastly, `includes=c('#include  <eureqa/eureqa.h>, <iostream>'` looks pretty wrong. Maybe you meant:

```
 include=c("#include <eureqa/eureqa/eureqa.h>", "include <iostream>")
```

instead.

Comment: this gives eurequa.h:http://code.google.com/p/eureqa-api/downloads/detail?name=eureqa_api_1_08_0.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: this gives boost c++ libraries which contains iostream: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.50.0/boost_1_50_0.zip/download?utm_expid=6384-3&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boost.org%2Fusers%2Fhistory%2Fversion_1_50_0.html